# Sorting content to reverse during implementation of infinity scroll in Django

Tags: python, django, infinite-scroll

I'm an introducer of Django.
Like Instagram, I'm trying to make pictures or videos come out when they go down.

I implemented pagination through infinite scrolling, but there was a problem that the posts that were previously reprinted and displayed in the latest order were not sorted in the latest order.

There are 10 posts (the higher the number, the more recent), and paginated_by is set to 4.

originally, it was 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1, but when I applied the infinite scroll, I could find the phenomenon that was reverted in the order of 4 3 2 1 8 7 6 5 10 9.

I'd like to apply the infinite scoll in order of 109 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1.
Please help me, thank you

here are my codes.

models.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
    status_choices = {
      ('before eating', '먹기전'),
      ('eating', '먹는중'),
  }

    restaurant = models.CharField(max_length = 128, verbose_name = '가게이름')
    foodname = models.CharField(max_length= 128, verbose_name= '음식이름')
    file = models.FileField()

    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    status =  models.CharField(max_length=80, choices= status_choices, null=True)
    distance = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='거리')


    title = models.CharField(max_length= 128, verbose_name= '제목', default= '모르겠어요')
    author = models.ForeignKey('user.meokda_user', on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = '작성자', null = True )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name = '등록시간')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('video:video_list')
```

views.py

```
class VideoListView(ListView):
    model = Video
    paginate_by = 4
    context_object_name = 'video_list'
    template_name = 'video/video_list.html'
```

video_list.html

```
 {% load static %}
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>

                    (생략)


  <div class="container text-center infinite-container">

    
    {% for video in video_list reversed %}
    <div class="card text-center mt-5 infinite-item">
    
      <div>  {{video.author }} 
        {% if request.session.user == 'gkuer' %} 
        <button class="btn btn-info" onclick = "location.href = '{% url 'video:video_delete' video.pk %}'">삭제</button>

      {% else %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
      <div class="card-header bg-transparent" >
        <div class="row">
          <a class="nav-link navbar-brand  text-muted mr-0" href="#"><h4>{{video.restaurant}}</h4></a>
          <a class="nav-link navbar-brand  text-muted ml-0 mt-1" href="#"><small>{{video.distance}}km</small></a>

          <a class="nav-link  navbar-brand  text-muted ml-auto" href="#">{{video.author}}</a>
          </li>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <a class="nav-link navbar-brand  text-muted mr-0" href="#">{{video.foodname}}</a>
          <a class="nav-link navbar-brand  text-muted ml-0 mt-1" href="#"><small>{{video.price | intcomma}}원</small></a>

          <a class="nav-link navbar-brand  ml-auto text-muted" href="#">{{video.get_status_display }}</a>
        </div>

    </div>


      <div class="card-body" style="padding:0;">
        <video class="center align-middle" controls muted autoplay loop style='max-width: 100%; max-height: 700px;'>
          <source src="{{ video.file.url }}" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

  </div>

  <div class="loading" style="display: none;">
    Loading...
  </div>
  
  {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">More</a>
  {% endif %}
  
  <script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
      onBeforePageLoad: function () {
        $('.loading').show();
      },
      onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
        $('.loading').hide();
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: you could try and add a orderby in you ListView Class like so `ordering = ['-created_at']`

Comment: I give you a cookie! thank you very much! it solved!